# javascript Json parse error Doubleqoutes

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

i am getting an error when i parse a json string in javascript.
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token Z" I know its for the double qoutes in the "Source" tag, but how do i parse this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = '[ { "Outcome": "Success", "Message": null, "Identity": "Request", "Delay": 0.115825, "BaseCurrency": "EUR", "QuoteCurrency": "USD", "Symbol": "EURUSD", "Date": "10/07/2015", "Time": "2:46:32 PM", "QuoteType": "Spot", "Bid": 1.12394, "Mid": 1.12397, "Ask": 1.124, "Spread": 0.00006, "Text": "1 European Union euro = 1.12397 United States dollars", "Source": "SIX Financial Information, Buyer = \"ZKB Zuercher Kantonalbank, Devisen\", Seller = \"ZKB Zuercher Kantonalbank, Devisen\"" }, { "Outcome": "Success", "Message": null, "Identity": null, "Delay": 0, "BaseCurrency": "GBP", "QuoteCurrency": "USD", "Symbol": "GBPUSD", "Date": "10/07/2015", "Time": "2:46:32 PM", "QuoteType": "Spot", "Bid": 1.5293, "Mid": 1.5295, "Ask": 1.5297, "Spread": 0.0004, "Text": "1 British pound sterling = 1.5295 United States dollars", "Source": "SIX Financial Information, Buyer = \"UBS Investment Bank\", Seller = \"UBS Investment Bank\"" } ]';
    var obj = JSON.parse(data); 
    for(var key in obj){
        console.log(obj[key].Symbol);       
    }
</script>
```

I could use replace methods but thats not a clean solution i think.

Comment: Using `\"` inside a quoted string as you have in `Source` is legal. See json.org.

Comment: ``\`` is a special character in string literals *and* JSON. Having JSON inside string literals is not really common. Why are you using JSON here in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you're using JSON here. Just do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = [ { "Outcome": "Success", "Message": null, "Identity": "Request", "Delay": 0.115825, "BaseCurrency": "EUR", "QuoteCurrency": "USD", "Symbol": "EURUSD", "Date": "10/07/2015", "Time": "2:46:32 PM", "QuoteType": "Spot", "Bid": 1.12394, "Mid": 1.12397, "Ask": 1.124, "Spread": 0.00006, "Text": "1 European Union euro = 1.12397 United States dollars", "Source": "SIX Financial Information, Buyer = \"ZKB Zuercher Kantonalbank, Devisen\", Seller = \"ZKB Zuercher Kantonalbank, Devisen\"" }, { "Outcome": "Success", "Message": null, "Identity": null, "Delay": 0, "BaseCurrency": "GBP", "QuoteCurrency": "USD", "Symbol": "GBPUSD", "Date": "10/07/2015", "Time": "2:46:32 PM", "QuoteType": "Spot", "Bid": 1.5293, "Mid": 1.5295, "Ask": 1.5297, "Spread": 0.0004, "Text": "1 British pound sterling = 1.5295 United States dollars", "Source": "SIX Financial Information, Buyer = \"UBS Investment Bank\", Seller = \"UBS Investment Bank\"" } ];
    for(var key in obj){
        console.log(obj[key].Symbol);       
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I am new in Json, but thanks i never had to parse it. It works!

Comment: @Vazzilly, please note, there is no JSON in my answer. There is only an object literal. There's a difference between JSON (which is always a string) and an object literal.

Comment: okay thanks learned that, because of the Data API that calls it Json ive called it Json aswell

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape your backslashes as well. Instead of `\"`, type `\\"`.